# Is it always impermissible to mix English definitions within mathematical expressions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I have this expression to define a sequence:

ℂ=()∈, ⊆

And all possible values of ℂ could be denoted as:

*C*={()∈:⊆}

However, if I needed to add more "where" clauses, could I add English to the statement like so:

*C*={()∈ where ⊆ and lh(*C*)>=4}

Or would it be more proper to denote it as:

*C*={()∈ : ⊆ : lh(*C*) >= 4}

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: I can't read the special symbols you used, so I can't comment on your specific example. But keep in mind that the notation in math is mostly just shorthand for proper English sentences where all "unnecessary" baggage has been removed. From a purely logical point of view, you can add as much English as you want, even drop all symbols like $\in,\exists,\dots$ and just replace everything with plain English, as long as you don't change the meaning of your writing. The most important thing is that your writing can be quickly understood, which usually takes a mix if symbols and proper English.

Comment: Most professional math papers do this. It is fine. Some people working in certain subfields such as mathematical logic or set theory may be less likely to use English words in certain circumstances, but this is the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: See also https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf